# Querying rental availability for date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am currently working on a web application to manage device rentals. I have **devices** that belong to one **device type** and are associated to **rentals** with a **start- and end date**.

I now want to display how many devices are available per type on each day in a given range, like so:

```
| Device Type: | 01.01 | 02.01 | 03.01 | 04.01 | 05.01 |
--------------------------------------------------------
|Laptop        |   10  |   10  |   10  |    5  |    5  |
|Mobile Phone  |   30  |   25  |   25  |   10  |   10  |
```

At the moment I find out the available devices for any given date as follows:

1. Find any rentals that overlap with the date
2. Get devices associated with those rentals
3. All devices not in 2. are available

The respective code looks like this:

```
  def Device.available_devices(start_date, end_date)
    other_rentals = Rental.where("outbound_delivery_date <= ? AND inbound_delivery_date >= ?", end_date, start_date)

    unavailable_devices = DeviceRental.where("rental_id IN (?)", other_rentals.map(&:id))

    if other_rentals.any? && unavailable_devices.any?
      @available_devices = Device.where("NOT devices.id IN (?)", unavailable_devices.map(&:device_id)).joins(:device_type).order("device_types.name")
    else
      @available_devices = Device.all
    end
  end
```

Now displaying this in a table means going through 1.-3. for each date and therefore causes an immense amount of DB queries which seems inefficient. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how I can get this data in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query by using `NOT IN`

```
available_devices = Device.where('devices.id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM device_rentals WHERE rental_id IN (SELECT rentals.id from rentals WHERE outbound_delivery_date <= ? AND inbound_delivery_date >= ?))', end_date, start_date)
```

to get the count...

```
available_devices.count
```

Comment: I think because of the DeviceRental model in between it actually needs to be "available_devices = Device.where('devices.id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM device_rentals WHERE rental_id IN (SELECT rentals.id from rentals WHERE outbound_delivery_date <= ? AND inbound_delivery_date >= ?))', end_date, start_date)", but is there a way I don't have to run this query once for each date in the range for which I want to know the availabilities?

Comment: Oh, one rental can cover multiple devices?  I assumes it was a many to one not a HABTM.  In any case, this answer brings you to one query per column item which (I tihink) is likely the best result you'll be able to get.  If you try to do multiple columns, will the returned phone belong to the first column?  The second?  I can't see how to resolve that without doing searches on the returned records for each column, which will be less efficient than a query for each column.

Comment: For this use case I actually just need the count of available devices for each device type on each date. I am now using the above query and then joining the device type, grouping by device type name and counting. Afterwards Loop through all device types and get the count from the hash previously generated and display it in the view.

Comment: Just use 'count' method on the query you've built (I've edited my answer to show that) ... it will do the query as SELECT COUNT which is the most efficient way to get the count... have SQL do it for you.

Comment: And yes, by all means, include device type in the query as you state.  If my answer was helpful, feel free to accept it or upvote it.